# How to improve my hashing algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

```
stper** pages;
int tableSize;    
struct Person{

    string name; 
    int age;    
    string homeTown;
};


void fonk1 (int numberOfBuckets)
{
    pages = new stper*[numberOfBuckets]();
    tableSize = numberOfBuckets;
} 

   int hashPerson(Person& person)
   {
    int hashVal = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < (person.getName()).length() ; i++)
        hashVal = 37*hashVal + (person.getName())[i];

    for (int i=0; i < (person.getHomeTown()).length() ; i++)
        hashVal = 37*hashVal + (person.getHomeTown())[i];   
    hashVal+= person.getAge();  

    hashVal %= tableSize;
    if(hashVal < 0)
        hashVal += tableSize;
    return hashVal;
   }
```

Hello everyone, I am new at hashing. My hashing function is at above in hashPerson function and asyou can see there are three key. Is my function a good algorithm for hashing and how can I improve the function and decrease the number of collision? (Please ignore if there are any syntax mistakes)

Comment: What's wrong with the hash function you have so far?  Do you have any reason to suspect you need to change it?

Comment: Your hash function is fine. But you're using C++, why not use the stl?

Comment: I just want to know if I can improve it and I do not know whether it is a good function or not.

Comment: I didn't use STL before. I will learn it.

Comment: What is the purpose of hashing based on all three variables? Do you frequently need to look up a person by their name, age, and home town?

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your hash can't distinguish between the end of someone's name and the start of their home town.  Jesse Jackson (no location) and Jesse from the town Jackson will collide.

Comment: @rrenaud, that's not quite right. One will hash "Jesse Jackson" and the other will hash "JesseJackson". But yes, on general principles, it's better to use different multipliers for different fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Use `unsigned` instead of `int`. In my experience this has proven to perform better, as when the unsigned overflows, it still stays non-negative(otherwise %-ing may lead to big problems - you get a negative index and ... a crash) and it also results in reduced collision rate(empirically proven). Also after all the function is supposed to return an index in a table so it is natural for the value to be unsigned - the index can not be negative.
2. Multiply hashVal by something when adding the age. I would suggest a value larger then any possible age for instance 200.
3. You never say what is `tableSize` but I would advice you to use some big(as big as possible) prime number, again to reduce collision rate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::hash` to generate good hash values for your basic components. You can find some examples and explanations [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

If you have a version of boost installed, you may find that `boost::hash_combine` does what you need. You can find boost's documentation with a good sample [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html).